# Run a single test method with maven

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, maven-2, maven-3

I know you can run all the tests in a certain class using:

```
mvn test -Dtest=classname
```

But I want to run an individual method and -Dtest=classname.methodname  doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I would be interested in knowing how to do this, too.  However, if I found myself doing it quite often, I think that test might be a candidate to be split out into its own class, so you can use the `mvn test -Dtest=classname` syntax.

Comment: Do you want to know how to do it via command line only?? 
Or using an IDE (eclipse) would work for you?

Comment: I was looking at a command line. I think the junit eclipse plugin will allow you to do this.

Comment: I did this for Maven 1. As I recalled, it involved making changes to JUnit, which is responsible for introspecting the test class.

Answer (score 942, accepted):

To run a single test method in Maven, you need to provide the command as:

```
mvn test -Dtest=TestCircle#xyz test
```

where `TestCircle` is the test class name and `xyz` is the test method.

Wild card characters also work; both in the method name and class name.

If you're testing in a multi-module project, specify the module that the test is in with `-pl <module-name>`.

For integration tests use `it.test=...` option instead of `test=...`:

```
mvn -pl <module-name> -Dit.test=TestCircle#xyz integration-test
```

Comment: I wish there was a way to merge answers... this is correct, but the link its taken from is in another post: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

Comment: I was wondering if the class name should be a fully qualified class name, with the package name, and the answer is, that while a fully qualified name works, also only the class name works, Maven looks the class up for you. I guess that if the name is ambiguous, it will emit an error.

Comment: Fixed the "No Tests Were Executed" error by downgrading to surefire 2.9

Comment: So wait, the "solution" is to revert to an old version?  What about those of us who actually require more recent versions of surefire?

Comment: I fixed "No Tests Were Executed!" by upgrading to 2.14:

Comment: If you're testing in a multi-module project, you also need to specify the module that the test is in with `-pl <module-name>`.

Comment: I had the same problem for testng with surefire 2.9, but version 2.14 and current last 2.17 work.

Comment: Use `-DfailIfNoTests=false` to skip projects without test. `No Tests Were Executed` happens when you try to run test from root project and there is modules without tests at all.

Comment: I got `No Tests Were Executed !` too, because i have `jUnit` and `TestNg` together in maven project dependencies. Removing `TestNg` or changing `@Test` annotation to `@org.testng.annotations.Test` solved problem for me.

Comment: When running integration tests the phase has to be "integration-test" instead of "test".

Comment: This command works !!
`mvn "-DTest=JoinTeamTestCases#validateJoinTeam" test`


Note that "-DTest" starts with UPPER CASE 'T'.

Comment: I just spent 45min with no success until I realized I was missing the "Test" at the end of my test class name.

Comment: Dont forget the **:** in front of the module name ... `mvn -pl :<module-name> -Dtest=TestCircle#xyz test`

Comment: For the first example, I found the `test` hanging off the end of the command to be unnecessary

Comment: What is the last `test` word being used for?

Comment: that is the goal maven needs to execute

Answer (score 36):

There is an issue with surefire 2.12.
This is what happen to me changing maven-surefire-plugin from 2.12 to 2.11:

1. `mvn test -Dtest=DesignRulesTest`

   > Result:
   >   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:**2.12**:test (default-test) on project pmd: **No tests were executed!**
2. `mvn test -Dtest=DesignRulesTest`

   > Result:
   >   [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:**2.11**:test (default-test) @ pmd ---
   >   ...
   >   Running net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.rule.design.DesignRulesTest
   >   Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 4, Time elapsed: 4.009 sec

Comment: Works again in 2.12.1 or later.

Comment: Fixed "No Tests Were Executed!" by upgrading to 2.14

Comment: If you use `@Category(IntegrationTest.class)`, use `-Dit.test=ClassName`, otherwise you will get `No tests were executed!` even with the latest plugin versions.

Answer (score 26):

## Run a single test method from a test class.

`mvn test -Dtest=Test1#methodname`

---

## Other related use-cases

- `mvn test // Run all the unit test classes`
- `mvn test -Dtest=Test1 // Run a single test class`
- `mvn test -Dtest=Test1,Test2 // Run multiple test classes`
- `mvn test -Dtest=Test1#testFoo* // Run all test methods that match pattern 'testFoo*' from a test class.`
- `mvn test -Dtest=Test1#testFoo*+testBar* // Run all test methods match pattern 'testFoo*' and 'testBar*' from a test class.`

Comment: superb solution

Answer (score 18):

What I do with my TestNG, (sorry, JUnit doesn't support this) test cases is I can assign a group to the test I want to run

```
@Test(groups="broken")
```

And then simply run 'mvn -Dgroups=broken'.

Comment: This is a good answer. In my case, the test tried to run but some Seam components weren't set up properly so it looks like this is skipping some portion of the setup code as well.

Comment: Correct. You need to either put groups=broken in in your @BeforeMethod, or do @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun=true)

Comment: Please let me know what is group here, since I am getting compilation issue.

Answer (score 17):

Running a set of methods in a Single Test Class
With version 2.7.3, you can run only n tests in a single Test Class.

NOTE : it's supported for junit 4.x and TestNG.

You must use the following syntax

```
mvn -Dtest=TestCircle#mytest test
```

You can use patterns too

```
mvn -Dtest=TestCircle#test* test
```

As of surefire 2.12.1, you can select multiple methods (JUnit4X only at this time, patches welcome)

```
mvn -Dtest=TestCircle#testOne+testTwo test
```

Check this [link about single tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html)

Comment: In my case i had to double quote the TestClass#test name like mvn -Dtest="TestCircle#myTest" test

Comment: @PratikKhadloya Any idea how it works for dependent tests? Say, I have test1(), test2(), test3() methods in TestClass and test2 depends on test1. How can I run just test2()?

Comment: I think if you have dependencies amongst your tests, you are doing something wrong. Each test should be independent of other tests. You need to remove the coupling between them.

Answer (score 15):

This command works !!
 `mvn "-DTest=JoinTeamTestCases#validateJoinTeam" test` Note that "-DTest" starts with UPPER CASE 'T'.

Comment: Does *not* work with SureFire 2.18.x; it just runs all tests.

Comment: This made a difference to me when using Java17

Answer (score 12):

You can run specific test class(es) and method(s) using the following syntax:

> 1. full package : mvn test -Dtest="com.oracle.tests.**"
> 2. all method in a class : mvn test -Dtest=CLASS_NAME1
> 3. single method from single class :mvn test -Dtest=CLASS_NAME1#METHOD_NAME1
> 4. multiple method from multiple class : mvn test -Dtest=CLASS_NAME1#METHOD_NAME1,CLASS_NAME2#METHOD_NAME2

Answer (score 10):

First you need to clean your maven project

`mvn clean`

then you can run specific file and function using

`mvn test -Dtest=testClassName#testCaseName`

Answer (score 9):

I tried several solutions provided in this thread, however they were not working for module which depends on a different one. In that case I had to run `mvn` from the root-module with additional parameters: `-am` (`--also-make`), which tells maven to built modules which your test module depends on and `-DfailIfNoTests=false`, otherwise "No tests were executed!" error appears.

```
mvn test -pl B -Dtest=MyTestClass#myTest -am -DfailIfNoTests=false
```

pom.xml section in root:

```
<modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>B</module>
<modules>
```

B depends on A.

Answer (score 4):

The *test* parameter mentioned by tobrien allows you to specify a method using a *#* before the method name. This should work for JUnit and TestNG. I've never tried it, just read it on the [Surefire Plugin page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html):

> Specify this parameter to run individual tests by file name, overriding the includes/excludes parameters. Each pattern you specify here will be used to create an include pattern formatted like **/${test}.java, so you can just type "-Dtest=MyTest" to run a single test called "foo/MyTest.java".
>   This parameter overrides the includes/excludes parameters, and the TestNG suiteXmlFiles parameter. since 2.7.3 You can execute a limited number of method in the test with adding #myMethod or #my*ethod. Si type "-Dtest=MyTest#myMethod" supported for junit 4.x and testNg

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the JUnit test class and its method to be executed.

```
mvn test -Dtest=com.mycompany.AppTest#testMethod
```

https://metamug.com/article/java/build-run-java-maven-project-command-line.html#running-unit-tests

Answer (score 3):

New versions of JUnit contains the Categories runner:
http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/doc/ReleaseNotes4.8.html

But releasing procedure of JUnit is not maven based, so maven users have to put it manually to their repositories.

Comment: Nice. But I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Subj is supported from 2.7.3 version of maven-surefire-plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

Answer (score 3):

As of surefire plugin version 2.22.1 (possibly earlier) you can run single test using testnames property when using testng.xml

Given a following testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="all-tests">
        <classes>
            <class name="server.Atest"/>
            <class name="server.Btest"/>
            <class name="server.Ctest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="run-A-test">
        <classes>
            <class name="server.Atest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="run-B-test">
        <classes>
            <class name="server.Btest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="run-C-test">
        <classes>
            <class name="server.Ctest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

with the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    [...]
    <properties>
        <selectedTests>all-tests</selectedTests>
    </properties>
    [...]
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <file>src/test/resources/testng.xml</file>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>testnames</name>
                        <value>${selectedTests}</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
</project>
```

From command line

```
mvn clean test -DselectedTests=run-B-test
```

Further reading - [Maven surefire plugin using testng](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html)

Answer (score -4):

You can run a single test class, but not a single method within a test class.   You use the simple name of the class not the fully-qualified name of the class.   So, if you have a test in "org.sonatype.test.MyTest" and that is the only test you want to run, your command line would look like this:

```
mvn test -Dtest=MyTest
```

Comment: I tested solution described on previous comments in a single module project,  so what this comment is saying is not true.

Comment: It may have been true in 2009 when originally answered.