# Using Maven, how do I run specific tests?

Tags: unit-testing, maven

I have thousands of unit tests in my project, and I'd like to choose one or a couple of them to run from the command line. What's the command to do that?

Comment: By method or class? Explicit for method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873995/run-a-single-test-method-with-maven

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can run all the tests in a class, by passing the `-Dtest=<class>` flag to Maven:

```
mvn clean test -Dtest=xxxxTest
```

Since Surefire 2.8, you can also run an individual test, say a method `testA` within your unit tests, using the same flag:

```
mvn clean test -Dtest=xxxxTest#testA
```

More examples for running multiple tests, by name pattern or name lists, can be found in the [Maven Surefire documentation > Running a Single Test](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html).

Comment: appears from http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html that you can also optionally also specifiy both test class *and* method name as well, is that right?

Comment: How about a list of classes? ie. 5 or 6 Test classes?

Comment: Although the Maven Surefire documentation title is 'Running a Single Test', it also explains how to run multiple tests. For example, `mvn -Dtest=TestSquare,TestCi*le test`

Answer (score 33):

Please read this piece of the [maven surefire plugin manual](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html). Basically you can do the following:

```
mvn -Dtest=*PerformanceTest clean test
```

Which only runs all the test classes ending in PerformanceTest.

Answer (score 4):

+1 to the above answers, *and*... make sure you're in the same directory of the module where the test you're trying to run lives.
I ran into this issue, because I normally work in multi-module projects and run `mvn clean install` from the root of the project... but for this use case, you need to `cd` into the module of the test you're trying to run.

Comment: Or use the `-pl <module>` option to run the tests in the specified module.

Comment: Thanks for the solution to a non-obvious problem!