# Maven: how run not all tests

Tags: maven

Understand that it is quite a stupid question, but i am new to Maven. 
I use JUnit+Maven, how can I configure Maven to run not all tests with @Test annotation, but only specific test classes?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html) helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Maven, how do I run specific tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568632/using-maven-how-do-i-run-specific-tests)

Comment: The link from Jens is exactly what I need - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run tests from single class by running

```
mvn clean test -Dtest=MyTestClass
```

Or you can even use simple regex such as

```
mvn -Dtest=*UserTest clean test
```

Answer (score -1):

Use @Ignore on the class.

```
@Ignore
public class TestClass {
```