# TestNG - Run single test by passing the test name though command line

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

Currently we are using maven profiling to run `testng` test suites. Below is my profile

```
<profile>
    <id>BAT_All</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/testplans/BAT_All.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

In this case we are using below `command` to run all the test cases in `BAT_All.xml` file and working as expected

```
mvn clean install -PBAT_All
```

Now I need to run single test case using test case name. I tried with below command but its not working.

```
mvn clean install -Dtest=verify_Home_Page_Title
```

Is it possible to run single test case with maven profiling

Comment: hi, look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568632/using-maven-how-do-i-run-specific-tests

Comment: What does "does not working" mean? Is no test run? Do you get an error? What stats does `Tests run:` report?

Answer (score -1):

```
mvn clean test -Dtest=classname#testname
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it is supposed to help.