# Running Junit5 tests on condition

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5, spring-boot-test

There is a way by which I can run junit tests only by adding arguments to the "mvn clean install" command? Without annotate tests with @Profile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Maven, how do I run specific tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568632/using-maven-how-do-i-run-specific-tests)

Comment: Why? What is the reason?

Comment: Technically you can make JUnit Jupiter run on particular conditions (JRE, @Enabled* details in the junit jupiter documentation https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/) but the question is why would you like to do that? Furthermore where is `@Profile` coming from? Ah I assume from spring boot. It has profiles but for tests in particular for unit tests it does not make sense...please give more details ...

Comment: Basically I'm using springboot, you're right and I have already an active profile ("dev"). On top of existing test I want to integrate JMH. Also JMH tests I want them to be run based on a condition. (ex: mvn clean install -Pdev -Drun=jmh) Something like this if it's possible.

Comment: Maybe tags are what you are looking for [Baeldung: Tagging and Filtering JUnit Tests](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-filtering-tests)

Comment: How about `mvn test` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with Junit5 what you appear to be looking for is one or more of the following annotations: `@EnabledIfSystemProperty`, `@DisabledIfSystemProperty`, `@EnabledIfEnvironmentVariable`, `@DisabledIfEnvironmentVariable`.

Refer to the user guide for some examples: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-conditional-execution