# Using Maven, how do I run a specific test when using JUnit test suites?

Tags: maven, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to figure out a Maven command to execute a single JUnit @Test method

However, I have the added complication that my JUnit tests are inside a test suite being called from a wrapper class (the wrapper sets up/tears down some test data, used by all the test classes)

Wrapper class:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({
   TestClassA.class,
   TestClassB.class,
})
public class TestWrapper
{
   @BeforeClass
   public static void dataSetup() throws Exception
   {
      //Create test data
   }
   
   @AfterClass
   public static void dataTeardown() throws Exception
   {
      //Remove test data
   }
}
```

Example test class:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
public class TestClassA
{
   @Test
   public void someTest()
   {
      //test contents
   }

   @Test
   public void anotherTest()
   {
      //test contents
   }
}
```

To execute all tests using the wrapper, I'm using the Maven command:

```
mvn verify -Dtest=**/TestWrapper test
```

I'm trying to figure out how to execute a specific test in one of the test suites, ex, only execute `TestClassA.someTest`

Currently, I'm just commenting out the test suites/test methods I want to skip, but there has to be a better way

This is very similar to the question here: [Using Maven, how do I run specific tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568632/using-maven-how-do-i-run-specific-tests)

As suggested in the linked question, I've tried using `-Dtest=**/TestWrapper#someTest`, but that fails because `someTest` isn't a method of `TestWrapper`

I've also tried `-Dtest="**/TestWrapper, **/TestClassA#someTest"`

That gets me a little closer, in that it does exactly what I want (runs `TestWrapper` and only executes `TestClassA.someTest`), but then it runs a second execution of `TestClassA.someTest` alone (which fails horribly because the wrapper test data doesn't exist)