# maven :: run only single test in multi-module project

Tags: unit-testing, maven, continuous-integration

Is there any way to provide some command-line argument in order to skip all tests but one on some module? So I will not need to change pom.xml every time I will need to run another test?

For example, I want to create build configuration on TeamCity, and provide command-line arguments to run only single test in some module. Next time I will need to change it and run another test, and so on.

Perhaps it is not how CI is intended to be used, but still.

Comment: Did you see this topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873995/run-a-single-test-method-with-maven and here some more: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html other than these I could not find.

Comment: @MaunoV.Actually if there are several modules, the test will fail. I found the solution: -Dtest=TestName -DfailIfNoTests=false

Answer (score 138, accepted):

I assume you've read the docs about [running a single test under surefire](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html)? What they don't tell you is how to do that in a sub-module:

```
mvn test -Dtest=testname -pl subproject -am
```

Where `subproject` is the project containing that test. From the mvn man page:

> -pl,--projects arg Comma-delimited list of specified reactor projects to build instead of all projects. A project can be specified by [groupId]:artifactId or by its relative path.

> -am,--also-make If project list is specified, also build projects required by the list

Comment: I wish there was a way of doing it without specifying the subproject so I don't have to think about it (I could do a bash for but it's ugly)

Comment: This solution doesn't work if the module to be tested depends on other subprojects.

Comment: @Vadzim, for me it helped to use `-DfailIfNoTests=false`: `mvn test -Dtest=testname -DfailIfNoTests=false`

Comment: If the module depends on other submodules, run `mvn install` on the parent project. The dependencies will be installed to your system and maven will find them when you run `mvn test` on the submodule.

Comment: you can also add -am (short for --also-make) to also build dependencies, if the sub-project you want to test depends on other sub-projects

Comment: @CiroSantilli刘晓波死六四事件法轮功 There is. Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869762/maven-run-only-single-test-in-multi-module-project/47493510#47493510).

Comment: @Vadzim @Abdull , `-DfailIfNoTests=false` will not work if the project is using the Surefire plugin to run tests. You should use `-Dsurefire.failIfNoSpecifiedTests=false` instead

Answer (score 56):

Other answers I see are not fully complete, for projects that depend on other sub-modules to be built. One option is to run `mvn install` to have the required jars to be installed into `~/.m2/...`, but that option is not very "clean".

Following command will build the sub-modules, and run only the test class that is specified. This is to be run at parent module level. Also, no need to specify sub-module name.

```
mvn test -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dtest={test_class_name} -am
```

*As an aside, this can also be `mvn clean test -Dfa.....`. I have a habit of always running `clean` when running tests.*

References.. 
`-am` will make all the other sub-modules.
`-DfailIfNoTests=false` does not fail the entire process since we are not intending to run tests in other modules.
`-pl` option is not needed since `-am` is already building everything

Comment: I find it runs slightly faster if I include the "-pl projectname".

Comment: Is there a way to run all the tests in a submodule and also build all the modules it depends on?
Something like mvn test -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dtest={moduleName} -am

Comment: @Anon wouldn't the comment from `@CurtisYallop` achieve that?

Comment: @DebosmitRay No. If I want to run tests from module1-test and module1-test depends on module2-test, then mvn test -pl module1-test -am will run tests from module2-test as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. saved me a headache.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer. The one currently marked as the correct one only works if you install artefacts to your local `.m2/repository` folder, which is something you do not want to do, especially if you are working on a multi module project. In fact, not having to `mvn install` is one of the main reasons to use multi modules.

On top of that, this answer conveniently allows one not to have to specify the project, which in 99.99% of cases is redundant.

Answer (score 15):

In case the module to be tested depends on other projects, solution works by changing commands as:

```
mvn test -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dtest=testname -pl subproject
```

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, if you have a multi-module project, you can run all tests with this command at parent directory.

```sh
mvn test -pl subproject
```

And the `subproject`'s name can be found by running the following command, usually in the form of `group-id:artifact-id`.

```sh
mvn help:active-profiles
```