# How can I run all tests of just one maven sub module?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I do need to build the modules it depends on first, but I don't want to run their tests. I've tried various invocations with `-am` `-pl`, this is the most recent, and based on [maven :: run only single test in multi-module project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11869762/206466)

```
mvn test -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dtest="**" -am -pl service-api test
```

All of these tests should be in the `com.myapp.service` package, and packages below it. Ideally though, an answer won't rely on that.

Nothing I have tried works though? What's the magic invocation to compile process-resources for dependents, and run tests for just this module?

Comment: Are the tests you want to run in a separate or identifiable package?

Comment: @aksappy yes they are

Comment: In that case, wouldn't this work? `mvn test -Dtest=com.myapp.service.*Test`

Comment: @aksappy that fails with "failIfNoTests". I tried adding that and doing this `mvn -Dtest="com.myapp.service.**.*Test" -DfailIfNoTests=false clean test ` the `**` added because it has a *root* package, but not all the tests are in just one package, and that didn't run any tests at all. I ran with `com.myapp.service.*Test` and that also didn't run any tests, probably because there aren't any for the root package.