# Run a single plug-in test method using tycho-surefire-plugin

Tags: unit-testing, maven, tycho, surefire, tycho-surefire-plugin

How can I run a single plug-in test method in Maven using tycho-surefire-plugin?

I tried the `-Dtest` option with #, but it doesn't work:

```
mvn clean install -Dtest=MyUITest#testDummy
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873995/run-a-single-test-method-with-maven).

However you can use [TestSuite](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~javaplt/javadoc/concjunit4.7/junit/framework/TestSuite.html) and [Filter](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~javaplt/javadoc/concjunit4.7/org/junit/runner/manipulation/Filter.html) to achieve what you want or even more customized selection of tests.

```
public class FilteredTests extends TestSuite {

public static TestSuite suite() {
    TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();

    suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(YourTestClass.class).filter(new Filter() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldRun(Description description) {
                return description.getMethodName().equals("Your_Method_name");
            }

            @Override
            public String describe() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        }));

    return suite;
}
```

}

Now configure tycho-surefire plugin to run this suite

```
<configuration>
                ...
                <testSuite>bundle.symbolic.name.of.test.plugin</testSuite>
                <testClass>package.of.test.suite.FilteredTests</testClass>
                ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: The accepted solution in the linked question is to use the hash character (`#`) as separator for the method name. According to Prasanth's question this doesn't work. Does it work for you?

Comment: I have the same issue, the # does not work for me either.

Comment: Can confirm the hash syntax does not work with the `tycho-surefire-plugin`. I've just resorted to ignoring the other test methods in my class, or moving it to a separate temporary class file and using `-Dtest=` to specify that class file. Frustrating that they don't maintain parity with the standard surefire plugin.

Comment: Frustrating indeed: the ${test} property in tycho-surefire only supports classes according to its documentation: https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-surefire/tycho-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test