# want ~/.m2/repository/ hierarchy of .jar s to be on CLASSPATH (with out causing [arg list too long] error)

Tags: java, classpath

Any body have tactics for doing this?   I hate babysitting the CLASSPATH.  From the Ksh, I try

```
for i in `find ~/.m2/repository/ -print`
do
   export CLASSPATH=$i:$CLASSPATH
done

echo $CLASSPATH //admittedly, very long
cd $MY_PROJ/target/test-classes/
java -cp .:$CLASSPATH  com.my.MyApp
```

//but this does not work [arg list too long] error

any ideas?

Comment: Why would you do that instead of letting maven pull in what it needs for a particular project?

Comment: becasue I have to run the test from a KornShell command line prompt

Comment: but why not just `mvn test`?

Comment: cuz i dont know how!  :-(  is there a way to say `mvn test` that only executes that one test case?

Comment: The maven repository can have a practically unlimited number of jars, which is why maven only grabs what it wants.  Almost any solution to get around the size limit for grabbing them all will just break again once you add another couple thousand jars to your maven repo.

Comment: Go take a look at the [Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html), it gives you more granularity with your testing than a vanilla `mvn test`.

Comment: This is also discussed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873995/run-a-single-test-method-with-maven

Comment: will this plugin allow me to work from a KornShell command line (or do I necessarily have to be in an IDE)?  I appreciate that my need to do this from a ksh command line may be arbitrary, but it is required.  thanks for your inputs BTW, appreciated.

Comment: AH.  Very nice.  thank you!  You have gifted me the solution and I am grateful.  Thank you.  :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54743/discussion-between-azurefrog-and-lri-cs).

Comment: i work at a bank and it is blocking my access to your chat invite.  :-(

Comment: but the link you provided brings me remedy!  thank you.