# Maven and JUnit 5: run a single test in a class

Tags: maven, junit5

I have been trying to run unsuccessfully a single test in one class with Maven (version 3.3.9) and JUnit 5 (NOT 4) with the command:

```
mvn -Dtest=EmitRulesTest#cr_filter_contact_points_for_C4C_output test
```

This command executes all tests.

Trying out this command actually executes all tests in the class:

```
mvn test -Dtest=EmitRulesTest
```

This is my JUnit 5 Maven configuration:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-RC2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        ...    
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertiesFile>${basedir}/src/test/resources/definitions/system.properties</systemPropertiesFile>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0-RC2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.0-RC2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Further references: [Running a Single Test using Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5988315/2735286)

Comment: According to the surefire plugin documentation, executing a set of methods (or one method) is [available only for JUnit 4.x](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html#Running_a_Set_of_Methods_in_a_Single_Test_Class)
.

Comment: Yes, you seem to be right about the fact that this is currently not possible.

Comment: The NetBeans IDE generates test classes using JUnit 5 now. We can track the issue there: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-3733

Answer (score 8):

You can use this format:

```
mvn test -Dtest=TestClass#testMethod
```

You can find out more information here: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

This is an excerpt of my POM.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.vintage.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

...

<properties>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.1.0</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.vintage.version>5.1.0</junit.vintage.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.1.0</junit.platform.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Does this apply to JUnit 5? This question is not about JUnit 4.

Comment: Yes, but it requires Platform 1.0.3 / Jupiter 5.0.3.

Comment: Like @MarcPhilipp said, this applies to JUnit 5.