# Unable to automate a dropdown of a web page using selenium webdriver C#

Tags: html, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfJKg.png)HTML tag of a web page I am trying to automate is as given below:

```html
<bodytag style="" xpath="1">
<input type="hidden" id="__ix_session__" value="Jh56EMR8-6e1MTOAbz28PFSMarIlOedZr1Sk">
<div data-v-17869350="" id="app">
<div data-v-30cf20dd="" data-v-17869350="" data-app="true" class="application theme--light" id="app">
<div class="v-menu__content theme--light menuable__content__active" style="">
<div class="v-select-list v-card theme--light" data-v-69717070="true">
<div class="v-list theme--light">
<div>
<a class="v-list__tile v-list__tile--link v-list__tile--active theme--light primary--text">
<div class="v-list__tile__content">
<div class="v-list__tile__title">
QA1
</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div>
<a class="v-list__tile v-list__tile--link theme--light">
<div class="v-list__tile__content">
<div class="v-list__tile__title" style="">
QA2
</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div>
<a class="v-list__tile v-list__tile--link theme--light">
<div class="v-list__tile__content">
<div class="v-list__tile__title">
QA3
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

I tried using javascript to automate hidden webelement but still no success. In above code Q1, Q2 and Q3 are dropdown values. Also tries using xpath and cssselector. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a single test method with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873995/run-a-single-test-method-with-maven). You can find solution in @bsk answer.

Comment: Post your code inside the question.