# Failing to call single junit test method using maven from command line

Tags: java, maven, junit4

I am using command like `mvn -q  -Dtest=MyJUnitTestClassName#runSingleTest test`as per maven & junit documentation it should run ONLY the `runSingleTest` test method. but problem is all tests are running.

I am using maven3 and junit4.

```
mvn -q  -Dtest=MyJUnitTestClassName#runSingleTest test
```

Comment: The name of the class does not follow the naming convention like `*Test.java` ..apart from that I doubt that things are running...

Comment: I tried both. i.e. giving fully qualified classname , still somehow it runs ALL methods in that class.

Answer (score 0):

Try quotes around your class and test (i.e. -Dtest="MyJUnitTestClassName#runSingleTest").  I use Maven 3.3 and JUnit 4 and the syntax you listed works for me, but that behavior sounds similar to issues with some versions of the SureFire plugins.

[Run a single test method with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873995/run-a-single-test-method-with-maven)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it didn't work. I still notice all methods are executed (or tested)