# Unknown lifecycle phase while executing maven command

Tags: java, maven, karate

I am using openjdk 17.6(temurin 17) and maven 3.9.3 to run my karate framework and I am getting following error while executing men command

**Unknown lifecycle phase .env. You must specify valid lifecycle phase**

Maven command
Mvn clean test -Dkarate.env=“qa” -Dkarate.options=“—-tags@sampletest”

Not sure why mvn command is failing.please help

Adding additional detials

following changes have been made to pom file

```
<maven.compiler.version>3.10.1</maven.compiler.version>
<maven.surefire.plugin>3.1.0</maven.surefire.plugin>
<karate.version>1.4.1RC2</karate.version>
<aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
```

getting following issue
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugin:3.10.1:testCompile
Fatal error compiling: Invalid target release 17

Comment: See also [_Run a single test method with maven_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1873995/230513).

Answer (score 2):

Replace -Dkarate.en=“qa” to -Dkarate.env=“qa”

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
-Dkarate.options="—t @sampletest"
```

Comment: I did tried as you suggested. But still I see the same issue. In intellij IDE terminal, when executed with command it says unknown lifecycle phase".env"

made changes to pom file with latest version as described in additional detials. still I am facing the same issue.

I tried running the same command in command prompt and it shows
fatal error compiling invalid target release : 17

Comment: @satishsrip sorry I give up. follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it was resolved when I switched intellij terminal from using powershell to using cmd